# How do I correctly use the lower and upper bound in a linear programming problem, in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I have the following Python code:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

f = [612.03, 619, 617.13, 923]
A = [[-94, -96, -94.3, -118.6],
     [-83.7, -83, -87.6, -89.7],
     [1.02, 0.51, 0, 0],
     [203.9, 214.5, 27.88, 78.2],
     [53.6, 70.7, 71.5, 5.95],
     [14.9, 0, 0, 0],
     [35.1, 73.7, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 34.7],
     [0, 0, 0, 100]]
b = [-95 * 8000, -85 * 8000, 8000, 210 * 8000, 90 * 8000, 18 * 8000, 35 * 8000, 2.7 * 8000, 5 * 8000]
Aeq = [[1, 1, 1, 1]]
beq = [8000]
lb = (0, 0, 0, 0)
ub = (6500, 8200, 2300, 1000)
x = linprog(c=f, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, A_eq=Aeq, b_eq=beq, bounds=[lb, ub])
print(x)
```

The problem is that, calling the `linprog` function, I get the following error message:

**ValueError: Invalid input for linprog: provide a 4 x 2 array for bounds, not a 2 x 4 array.**

I understand that `lb` and/or `ub` need to have other dimensions, but I don't know how should I modify the code above to fix this problem.

Can you help me?

Comment: `bounds=np.transpose([lb, ub])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` to stack your bounds:

```
x = linprog(c=f, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, A_eq=Aeq, b_eq=beq, bounds=list(zip(lb, ub)))
```

or suggested by @Dogbert: `bounds=np.transpose([lb, ub])`

Output:

```
     con: array([3.40828974e-05])
     fun: 4994935.113634065
 message: 'The solution does not satisfy the constraints within the required tolerance of 3.16E-04, yet no errors were raised and there is no certificate of infeasibility or unboundedness. Check whether the slack and constraint residuals are acceptable; if not, consider enabling presolve, adjusting the tolerance option(s), and/or using a different method. Please consider submitting a bug report.'
     nit: 12
   slack: array([-3.20955238e-03, -2.88944331e-03,  2.61599181e+03,  4.84812319e+05,
        2.57957512e+05,  6.75648360e+04,  7.80431940e+04,  1.21269712e+04,
        1.27002053e+04])
  status: 4
 success: False
       x: array([5129.87677757,  297.12525211, 2299.99998936,  272.99794688])
```